# Unmarshaling XML into Go struct not working for arrays

Tags: go, unmarshalling

The following [code](https://play.golang.org/p/jy0qleu_OI8), but the XML unmarshaling does not produce the expected result.  I'm attempting to add JSON and XML tags to a Go struct to be able to use the same struct for multiple encodings.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type EndpointKind string

const (
    Unix EndpointKind = "unix"
    Tcp4 EndpointKind = "tcp4"
    Tcp6 EndpointKind = "tcp6"
)

func (ek *EndpointKind) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    type EK EndpointKind

    var r *EK = (*EK)(ek)
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &r)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    switch *ek {
    case Unix, Tcp4, Tcp6:
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("invalid EndpointKind: %s", *ek))
}

func (ek *EndpointKind) UnmarshalXML(dec *xml.Decoder, _ xml.StartElement) error {
    type EK EndpointKind

    var r *EK = (*EK)(ek)
    err := dec.Decode(&r)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    switch *ek {
    case Unix, Tcp4, Tcp6:
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("invalid EndpointKind: %s", *ek))
}

type Endpoint struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `json:"-" xml:"Endpoint"`
    Kind  EndpointKind `json:"kind" xml:"Kind"`
    Value string       `json:"value" xml:"Value"`
}

type Ingress struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name   `json:"-" xml:"Ingress"`
    Endpoint []Endpoint `json:"endpoints"`
}

func main() {
    var obj = Ingress{
        Endpoint: []Endpoint{
            Endpoint{Kind: Tcp4, Value: "127.0.0.1:80"},
        },
    }
    var out, _ = xml.Marshal(obj)
    fmt.Println(string(out[:]))
    out, _ = json.Marshal(obj)
    fmt.Println(string(out[:]))

    var x = new(Ingress)

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`
    {"endpoints":[{"kind":"tcp4","value":"127.0.0.1:80"}]}
    `), &x)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", x)

    var y = new(Ingress)
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(`
    <Ingress>
          <Endpoint>
            <Kind>tcp4</Kind>
            <Value>127.0.0.1:80</Value>
          </Endpoint>
    </Ingress>
    `), &y)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", y)
}
```

This outputs:

```
<Ingress><Endpoint><Kind>tcp4</Kind><Value>127.0.0.1:80</Value></Endpoint></Ingress>
{"endpoints":[{"kind":"tcp4","value":"127.0.0.1:80"}]}
&{{ } [{{ } tcp4 127.0.0.1:80}]}
&{{ Ingress} []}
```

I expected to see:

```
<Ingress><Endpoint><Kind>tcp4</Kind><Value>127.0.0.1:80</Value></Endpoint></Ingress>
{"endpoints":[{"kind":"tcp4","value":"127.0.0.1:80"}]}
&{{ } [{{ } tcp4 127.0.0.1:80}]}
&{{ Ingress} [{{ } tcp4 127.0.0.1:80}]}
```

Is there a problem with the XML tagging I can fix to match the expectations?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my `UnmarshalXML` method was coded incorrectly:

```
func (ek *EndpointKind) UnmarshalXML(dec *xml.Decoder, s xml.StartElement) error {
    type EK EndpointKind

    var r *EK = (*EK)(ek)
    err := dec.DecodeElement(&r, &s) // NOTE the use of the start element
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    switch *ek {
    case Unix, Tcp4, Tcp6:
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("invalid EndpointKind: %s", *ek))
}
```